# Negative peak detector hits "minimum" value

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, analog, ltspice

I am using LTSpice simulation to average value of a function. To do that I detect positive and negative peaks and average them together. My function, however, starts at ~-3.3V. And the circuit I am using is unable to register any negative peak values lower than ~-1.7V. It results in this:
 [image: Simulation results]

What changes should I make to my circuit for it to be able to detect lower values of negative peaks?
[image: Circuit]
Vdd=5V; Vee=-5V;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input common mode range is the problem: -

- The signal input voltage range for an LT1057 starts from about 3.5 volts above the lowest supply voltage. If your lowest supply voltage is -5 volts, then all bets are off if the input is lower than -1.5 volts
- The output voltage swing may get to within 2 volts of the negative rail.

These are typical figures only. I'd look for a different device or increase the supply voltage levels.

Comment: Good point. Also I don't see a minimum supply voltage in the datasheet, all parameters are given for +-15V. No guarantee that it works at all at+-5V

Comment: @Dorian a very good point. I double checked (assuming it would be good for +/- 5 volts) but there is absolutely no indication it can be used at anything other than +/-15 volts. Poor specification I reckon. Good spot.